# AMD Phenom II x4 940 Black edition Pinout?

Tags: cpu, power, am2+

So I got an AMD Phenom II x4 940 Black Edition. The number on it is HDZ940XCJ4DGI. It uses an AM2+ socket. I think the important part is the socket, but I'm not sure. I'm trying to find the power and ground pins on the CPU, but I can't seem to find the processor's datasheet online (just it's specs list).

I also searched for "am2+ pinout" and "am2+ socket pinout". Nothing came up for either search.

Where can I find the pinout for my processor? How do I know which is power and which is ground?

Thanks!

evamvid

Comment: Why do you need pinout for a CPU?

Comment: So after a little more searching I found [these](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/46878.pdf) [two](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/31875.pdf) PDFs, but neither has the information I need. You'll notice that the second one talks about the AM2 socket; but I couldn't find a similar sheet for the AM2+.

Comment: @gronostaj I'm trying to put power through it to generate heat. See [this Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Hot-Plate/?ALLSTEPS) and [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSgW9AMeIjo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a caveat - keep yourself safe.  Electricity can kill - easily.  If you want to turn it into a heater, those CPU can easily get hot enough to catch fire.  Especially if there's no automatic overheating safety mechanism, which there won't be.  If in doubt, leave it alone.  Safety lesson over and on to the fun part-

The pin configuration for 940 pin AMD sockets-

http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/31412.pdf

The AM2 socket design specifications-

http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/31875.pdf

I realise you're after AM2+, but considering the AM2+ CPUs work in AM2 motherboards (and vice versa) I can't imagine the pin configurations would be different.

Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_AM2%2B suggests two things:

1) "The main differences between Socket AM2 and AM2+ socket processors are as follows:
HyperTransport 3.0 operating at up to 2.6 GHz
Split power planes: one for the CPU cores, and the other for the Integrated Memory controller (IMC). This will improve power savings, especially with integrated graphics, if the CPU cores are in sleep mode but the IMC is still active."

If true, then the voltage and ground pins will remain the same.

2) "While technical documentation was readily available for earlier generations of AMD processor sockets, the "AM2r2 Processor Functional Data Sheet" (AMD document number 41607) has not been made publicly available."

However, no source is given for either of these.

If the CPU is dead, there's no harm trying any pins you feel like, really... 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the doc I was looking for...but I'm still having trouble identifying the pins I'm looking for; I've found a couple of spots I'm hopeful about, but do you know how I can find the necessary power and ground pins?

Comment: I found in the pin descriptions that VSS is ground, but there are lots of pins that are VSS; I need to know the necessary power pins, and can't find them...

Comment: Also on page 75 there are some values, but I'm still unsure as to which pins it's referring to...

Comment: Also on page 23, I see several pins labeled VDDIO....is this the power pin I'm looking for?

Comment: Looking at the table on starting on page 26, there are lots of VDDs, VDDIO's, and VSS's....how do I tell which one(s) I want?...these really should have gone in a question edit...oh well!

Comment: New info! on page 45, it says VDD is the core power supply and VSS is the ground...like I was saying before, there are lots of these....

Comment: Sorry for flooding your inbox!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You might have to do a bit of experimentation on this one, my friend.
 
Use an AA battery (1.5v) before you use any USB (5v!) ports, of course.  I'd give it a shot with any of the VSS and VDD pins, and see if the CPU warms up a bit.